# How to know if two NSDate are in the same day

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nsdate

Do you know how to know if two `NSDate` are the same day. I want to take into account the locale...

It could be easy to use a `timeIntervalSinceDate:` but Monday 23H58 and Tuesday 00H01 are not in the same day...

Dealing with `NSDate` and locale for calculation is not very easy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *componentsForFirstDate = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:firstDate];

NSDateComponents *componentsForSecondDate = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:secondDate];

if ([componentsForFirstDate year] == [componentsForSecondDate year])
```

etc.

I don't know if `isEquals` would do what you want on `NSDateComponents`.

Comment: [NSCalendar currentCalendar] is painfully slow, so cache it if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by "caching" currentCal ? I put it in a singleton ?

Comment: Or create a category on NSCalendar where the result of currentCalendar is stored as a static variable.

Comment: As of iOS 7 `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]` is cached by the OS so no need to cache locally any more.

Answer (score 10):

Since iOS 8 this is straightforward:

```
let isSameDay = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().isDate(date1, inSameDayAsDate: date2)
```

and it becomes a little simpler yet with **Swift 3**:

```
let isSameDay = Calendar.current.isDate(date1, inSameDayAs: date2)
```

Answer (score 8):

Use NSCalendar and NSDateComponents for that:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps1 = [cal components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit| NSYearCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) 
                                      fromDate:date1];
NSDateComponents *comps2 = [cal components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit| NSYearCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) 
                                      fromDate:date2];


BOOL sameDay = ([comps1 day] == [comps2 day] 
                  && [comps1 month] == [comps2 month] 
                  && [comps1 year] == [comps2 year]);
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift:

```
func isSameDays(date1:NSDate, _ date2:NSDate) -> Bool {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    var comps1 = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Month , NSCalendarUnit.Year , NSCalendarUnit.Day], fromDate:date1)
    var comps2 = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Month , NSCalendarUnit.Year , NSCalendarUnit.Day], fromDate:date2)

    return (comps1.day == comps2.day) && (comps1.month == comps2.month) && (comps1.year == comps2.year)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Do it with NSDateFormatter :

```
NSDateFormatter *_df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
_df.dateFormat = @"yyyy.MM.dd";
NSString *_d1 = [_df stringFromDate:_date1];
NSString *_d2 = [_df stringFromDate:_date2];
if ([_d1 isEqualToString:_d2] == YES)
{
    // d1 and d2 is on same day/month/year
}
[_df release];
```

Answer (score 1):

If your app is going to running in OS X 10.9+ or iOS 8+ only, you can use the new APIs of `NSCalender`.

```
/*
    This API compares the given dates down to the given unit, reporting them equal if they are the same in the given unit and all larger units.
*/
- (BOOL)isDate:(NSDate *)date1 equalToDate:(NSDate *)date2 toUnitGranularity:(NSCalendarUnit)unit NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 8_0);
```

There are also a lot of convenient APIs. However, Apple hasn't mentioned them in their doc set. Anyway, the APIs are public and you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

Set timeZone if the date is not system locale.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:self.cityData.timeZone];
[calendar setTimeZone:timeZone];
NSDateComponents *componentsForFirstDate = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:weatherDataDate];
NSDateComponents *componentsForSecondDate = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:yesterday];            
if ([componentsForFirstDate day] == [componentsForSecondDate day]) {
    // TODO: 
}
```