# Filter an array of items by their date parameter without taking time into account

Tags: ios, swift, filter, nsdate

I have an array of Dates which I'd like to filter, depending on a date selected by a user. However, since each object has also time, I am having a hard time filtering correctly.

In my table view, I would like to filter this array of items by their date parameter without it comparing the time. Aka:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.filter({$0.date == selectedDate}).count
        //count is always 0 because time is not exactly the same in any instance
    }
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: This could could end up being really slow, it would be doing a separate filter operation for every section load. I Would suggest you use a dictionary mapping sections (dates?) to items

Comment: See [How to know if two NSDate are in the same day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833963/how-to-know-if-two-nsdate-are-in-the-same-day), in particular https://stackoverflow.com/a/35758876/1187415.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this function of the **system calendar**

```
Calendar.current.isDate($0.date, inSameDayAs: selectedDate)
```

Here is the apple documentation for this function in case you have an additional clarifying questions

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2292885-isdate